# How to change data-role "content" in ui-popup theme?

Tags: jquery-mobile, themes

i try to customize the theme of jquery mobile. In the documentation of "ui-popup" i found two options that I can change concerning theming:

```js
$.mobile.popup.prototype.options.overlayTheme = "jobstaff-de"; 
$.mobile.popup.prototype.options.theme = "jobstaff-de";
```

This results the following:

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="loginDialog" class="ui-body-jobstaff-de"  data-theme="jobstaff-de" data-overlay-theme="jobstaff-de">...</div>
```

So far so good. My question refers to the inner html of this div-area. I found this in it:

```html
<div data-role="content" class="ui-body-c" data-theme="c" role="main">...</div>
```

Why the theme is reset to "c" here? Do I need to change something else?

Thanks for any help!!

---

**EDIT 1** for Orma: the following themes I changed, too. I've put them into a file called jquery.mobile.theme.js which is loaded after jquery.js but before jquery.mobile.js:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.mobile.theme.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.mobile.js'></script>
```

content of jquery.mobile.theme.js: (jquery.js and jquery.mobile.js are unchanged)

```html
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {

    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme               = "jobstaff-de";
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme         = "jobstaff-de";  
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme        = "jobstaff-de";
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme         = "jobstaff-de";
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme        = "jobstaff-de"; 

    // Popups
    $.mobile.popup.prototype.options.overlayTheme       = "jobstaff-de"; 
    $.mobile.popup.prototype.options.theme              = "jobstaff-de"; 

    // listviews
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.headerTheme     = "jobstaff-de";  // Header for nested lists
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.theme           = "jobstaff-de";  // List items / content
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.dividerTheme    = "jobstaff-de";  // List divider
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.splitTheme      = "jobstaff-de";
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.countTheme      = "jobstaff-de";
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterTheme     = "jobstaff-de";

    // selectmenu
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.menuPageTheme = "jobstaff-de"; 
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.overlayTheme  = "jobstaff-de"; 
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.theme         = "jobstaff-de"; 

    // dialog
    $.mobile.dialog.prototype.options.theme             = "jobstaff-de"; 

    // panel
    $.mobile.panel.prototype.options.theme              = "jobstaff-de"; 

    //input
    $.mobile.textinput.prototype.options.theme          = "jobstaff-de"; 

    // buttons
    $.mobile.button.prototype.options.theme             = "jobstaff-de"; 


});
```

Comment: are you also changing the default theme of _page_? Are you loading the above code after jquery and before jquery mobile?

Comment: Please show us your code Tobias

Comment: it looks like the problem is caused by `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme`. If you remove that line, popup contents will be themed 'e' as in this example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YNC3C/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never modified themes like this :-)

Why don't you just write your `jobstaff-de` theme (which I assume you have) and manually set it on your JQM page:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="jobstaff-de">
  // all widgets will inherit jobstaff-de
</div>
```

In JQM 1.4, this single theme declaration should be enough to inherit the theme to all widgets on the page without having to specify it again - so no need to overwrite any defaults IMHO.

Comment: Version 1.4 is in alpha state at the moment, but I think this is the most helpful answer in the future for people which have the same problem. So I have to wait until the 1.4 is released ;) Thanks for your advice!